# Reading /dev/ttyUSB0 gives corrupted data

Tags: usb, corrupt, raspbian

I'm trying to read on `/dev/ttyUSB0` but I'm receiving corrupted data, I already tried `cat`, `dd` and `libusb` bindings for Node.js, all have the same result.

The device attached to that USB port sends a constant flow of data and I think that the OS might be the problem.

I'm using the data flow to build charts. I can see that corrupted data in the charts as a regular and sequential errors.

I'm using `Raspbian`, is there anything that I can do to tell the OS to execute just my program and nothing more?

Answer (score 0):

I presume you have verified the port is configured to the correct baud/ flow/ etc settings?

stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 -a

Comment: Is the data printable? If not I suppose it's possible a control character is coming through unescaped.  If the data is printable, do you have minicom installed?  You could see the stream with that.

Answer (score 0):

The solution we pick is to use libusb instead. Yes it involves developing user land applications to cope with. We also see some issues with /dev/ttyUSBx. The driver path is too long, it involves too many individual drivers, any problem in any of those drivers would cause a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem and neither minicom nor kermit worked and I'm almost sure that it was because of non printable chars.

Using [pyserial](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/) in python everything worked like a charm.

It's extremely easy to use. As an example:

```
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 9600, timeout=1)
x= ser.read()          # read one byte
s = ser.read(10)        # read up to ten bytes (timeout)
line = ser.readline()   # read a '\n' terminated line
ser.close()
```

You can find more examples on the [documentation](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/shortintro.htm).